# Updating Windows registry on a disk image

Tags: windows, windows-registry, disk-image

I have a hard disk image (.vmdk) taken from an old computer. The image contains a Windows 2000 installation.

Now I would like to update the registry on the image to make it bootable. (I'm suffering from this problem when booting the vmdk in VirtualBox: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314082/EN-US)

My question: Is there a tool that allows me to specify the registry changes (called "mergeide.reg") **and** the registry to be updated?

I.e., I want to run something like:

`C:\>magictool mergeide.reg m:\WINNT\system32\config\system`

where m: is the mounted VMDK image.

I didn't find anything useful on google. All available tools seem to allow updating only the registry of the **running** system.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: regedit can load hives, perhaps that'll help?

Answer (score 1):

You could try libguestfs, if you run Linux:

Taken from [virt-winreg](http://libguestfs.org/virt-win-reg.1.html)'s manpage, part of `libguestfs`:

> This program is only meant for simple access to the registry. If you
>   want to do complicated things with the registry, we suggest you
>   download the Registry hive files from the guest using libguestfs(3) or
>   guestfish(1) and access them locally, eg. using hivex(3), hivexsh(1)
>   or hivexregedit(1).

See [hivexregedit](http://libguestfs.org/hivexregedit.1.html)'s manpage for details.

Alternative options [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/21788/how-to-edit-registry-hives-without-live-running), most prominently booting `WinPE` and running this:

> Run regedit,
>
> select `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
>
> File --> "Load Hive..."
>
> The registry files are located in `XYZ:\Windows\System32\Config` of the
>   partition you are trying to edit.